# What could affect Python string comparison performance for strings over 64 characters?

Tags: python, string, performance, time-complexity

I'm trying to evaluate if comparing two string get slower as their length increases. My calculations suggest comparing strings should take an amortized constant time, but my Python experiments yield strange results:

Here is a plot of string length (1 to 400) versus time in milliseconds. Automatic garbage collection is disabled, and `gc.collect` is run between every iteration.

[image: Time vs string length]

I'm comparing 1 million random strings each time, counting matches as follows.The process is repeated 50 times before taking the min of all measured times.

```
for index in range(COUNT):
    if v1[index] == v2[index]:
        matches += 1
    else:
        non_matches += 1
```

What might account for the sudden increase around length 64?

**Note**: The following snippet can be used to try to reproduce the problem assuming `v1` and `v2` are two lists of random strings of length `n` and COUNT is their length.

```
timeit.timeit("for i in range(COUNT): v1[i] == v2[i]",
  "from __main__ import COUNT, v1, v2", number=50)
```

**Further note**: I've made two extra tests: comparing string with `is` instead of `==` suppresses the problem completely, and the performance is about 210ms/1M comparisons.
Since interning has been mentioned, I made sure to add a white space after each string, which should prevent interning; that doesn't change anything. Is it something else than interning then?

Comment: You should probably include the exact version of Python, just in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Since the strings are random, the comparison process will almost always stop at the first character. So what you are most likely seeing is just memory management issues - *new*ing them, filling them with random contents, etc.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Python does not compare strings on a character by character base - it uses a hash of the strings for doing so.

Comment: @Mike,I'm not timing the creation, only the comparison.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble believing the y axis is right. It should not take 200 **milliseconds** to compare two strings of length 5.  *Maybe* microseconds back in 2012. On my Intel i7 CPU (64 bit) it takes under a nanosecond for over 25 characters (when they match, so no short-circuiting happening). Something smells fishy...Just run it folks: `%time 'asdfsdsfsadfdsf' == 'asdfsdsfsadfdsf'`

Comment: @eric "I'm comparing 1 million random strings each time" is right there in the post

Comment: ok it wasn't clear you took the sum of a million operations from your post (vs the min of a million or whatever). So we are talking about a 6 microsecond increase at ~50 characters. This is much less alarming.

Comment: Following up on the rest of your comment: the equality comparison you showed *does* short-circuit, because both of these strings are interned, so your comparison is just a pointer comparison.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python *can* 'intern' short strings; stores them in a special cache, and re-uses string objects from that cache.

When then comparing strings, it'll first test if it is the same pointer (e.g. an interned string):

```
if (a == b) {
    switch (op) {
    case Py_EQ:case Py_LE:case Py_GE:
        result = Py_True;
        goto out;
// ...
```

Only if that pointer comparison fails does it use a size check and `memcmp` to compare the strings.

Interning normally only takes place for identifiers (function names, arguments, attributes, etc.) however, not for string values created at runtime.

Another possible culprit is string constants; string literals used in code are stored as constants at compile time and reused throughout; again only one object is created and identity tests are faster on those.

For string objects that are not the same, Python tests for equal length, equal first characters then uses the `memcmp()` function on the internal C strings. If your strings are *not* interned or otherwise are reusing the same objects, all other speed characteristics come down to the `memcmp()` function.

Comment: I thought that was the case but the interning pattern on my machine seems highly irregular: repeating `id('ss')` will give same results, but repeating `id('ssssss')` will give different ones each time. And repeating `id('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss')` will return the same results again too. Do you know why? Maybe I should ask it as a separate question..

Comment: In my Python 2.7.3, `id('ss')` gives different results each time, while `id('ssssss')` and `id` on the long string` consistently return the same number.

Comment: @larsmans I am also on python 2.7.3 on OS X. What I am not sure is whether "short strings" are interned and long strings aren't. Because `id(LONG_STRING)` will give me the same results too for certain lengths.

Comment: Store the string in a variable; interning does not always make the string immortal; it'll re-use the memory address for new strings. Sometimes running `id('onestring')` then `id('anotherstring')` gives the same memory address too.

Comment: I'm out of time today to go hunting for the exact interning rules, would love to do so though. I'd say, make it a new question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Cool, will do :)

Comment: You're right, storing in a variable changes the behavior. Strange, I'd thought the REPL's `_` would always keep the previous expression's value alive.

Comment: @larsmans: `_` is set to the return value of `id()`, not the string literal you called it on. :-)

Comment: Damn right :) Still, my CPython seems not to cache strings of length < 5, but I don't feel like digging for the interning rules either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still troubled by something though: I had considered interning as a possible cause, but I had discarded it as not explaining the steady increase between 64 and 100 characters; do you know where this could come from?

Comment: Strangely enough, if I make sure that strings end with a white space, and therefore are not interned, I get the same behaviour...

Answer (score 4):

I am just making wild guesses but you asked "what might" rather than what does so here are some possibilities:

- The CPU cache line size is 64 bytes and longer strings cause a cache miss.
- Python might store strings of 64 bytes in one kind of structure and longer strings in a more complicated structure.
- Related to the last one: it might zero-pad strings into a 64-byte array and is able to use very fast SSE2 vector instructions to match two strings.

Comment: Hi Zan, thanks for the answer! I looked at Python's implementation, but I couldn't find anything like this... Do you know where I could look? Also, do you know what could account for the steady increase for lengths from ~64 to ~100?

Comment: I looked at the source. There doesn't seem to be anything going on with how python handles strings that changes at that length, but the cache miss sounds very reasonable.